# Validation Cant Show on Last Option Radio Button with Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, validation, bootstrap-4

I have a radio button with Bootstrap 4, but when i using validation this error message show on below of first option radio button. How to show it on below of last option radio button?

Screenshot
[image]

HTML Code

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <legend class="col-form-label col-md-2 offset-2 pt-0 pr-0">Sudah pernah daftar? <span class="text-danger">*</span></legend>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="is_registered" id="option1" value="Belum" required="">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="option2">
          Belum
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="is_registered" id="option2" value="Sudah" required="">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="option1">
          Sudah
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript Code

```
errorElement: "em",
keyUp: true,
errorPlacement: function ( error, element ) {
  // Add the `help-block` class to the error element
  error.addClass('invalid-feedback');

  if (element.prop('type') === 'checkbox') {
    error.insertAfter(element.parent('label'));

  } else if (element.prop('type') === 'radio') {
    error.insertAfter(element.next('label'));
    $('.invalid-feedback').css("display", "block");
    
  } else if (element.hasClass('select2') && element.next('.select2-container').length) {
    error.insertAfter(element.next('span'));

  } else {
    error.insertAfter(element);
  }
},
```

Comment: Hi, can you make this runnable ?

Comment: here its https://codepen.io/pandyandi/pen/gOgeRoy

Comment: change this `error.insertAfter(element.next('label'))` to `error.insertAfter(element.closest('.col-md-6').find(".form-radio:last label"));`

Comment: okaay it works, much thanksss!